# Does this character  have a meaning or pronunciation?

Tags: glyph-origin, character-components

I'm trying to find the meaning of  which appears as component of characters in several languages.  Here there is a reference to it, but it gives no meaning or pronunciation.

Does this character  have a meaning or pronunciation?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[zisea](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=21D42)

> ㈠ 拼音mei3，同【美】。
> ㈡ 楚国文字隶定字，同【闵】。见【清華．尹至．簡01】

is a variant of「美」and/or「闵」and seems to keep those pronunciations, although the「min」reading isn't explicitly alluded to.

Although, I'm sure you're looking at the final /ei/ in 微 and now in the given /美 variant and seeing some sort of pattern. Not sure how much weight there is to that though.